# Magento checkout steps not numbering/indexing correctly

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I have successfully added a stage to our checkout process - I followed the official magento [documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_step.html)

However, the last stage to the checkout is not being numbered properly. Any ideas as to why? Through inspect element I can see that the numbers are coming from the ::before attribute.

Here is a picture of what's happening:
[image]

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, magento only specifies the content of the ::before on the checkout steps for the first 2 (1,2).

All you need to do is add this to your css if you have this problem:

```
.checkout-index-index .opc-progress-bar .opc-progress-bar-item:nth-child(3) > span:before {content: '3' !important;}
```

If you have more steps, simply copy the line again and change the numbers accordingly.

Now the checkout numbers all of the steps (1,2,3):

[image]